# Google Play Services Library Error onesignal

Tags: android, onesignal

for a one year using onesignal to send notification , recently occured an error although the APP is installed and users are added, in sectoin "all users" notification is not reachable.

error:
google Play services library initialization error. Check for conflicting plugins and make sure "com.google.android.gms.version" is in your AndroidManifest.xml. Check the logcat for more details..

i added

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

and i have this code in buil.gradle

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.4'
// Required for OneSignal, even if you have added FCM.
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

please help me.

Comment: Did you add OneSignal's Gradle Plugin to your setup? It works well with keeping dependencies up to date: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup#section-1-gradle-setup

Comment: I have the same issue, did you succeed to solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It also happened to me. I tried many things about libraries, versions and got frustrated.

Finally, I created a new App in Onesignal. As soon as I put the new token, it started to work. No idea why, but if this is an option for you, you can try